# Docker image's ID and sha256 are this field related and how generated

Tags: docker

As stated in title:

- There is a relationship between Docker's image ID and image sha256? (If I type `docker images --no-trunc` I get sha256 as image id)
- How image IDs are calculated? It is randomic?
- How sha256 is calculated? As far as I know is related with image's content. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Prior to Docker 1.10 image IDs were random, but since then they are generated deterministically using hashes (SHA256 currently). Each image layer has a digest which is a hash of its contents. The image ID is a different digest, hashed from the configuration - which includes the digests of its layers.

You can see the different digests in the image list and the history:

```
> docker images --digests                                                                                                                                   
REPOSITORY                  TAG                 DIGEST                                                                    IMAGE ID          CREATED       
ubuntu                      latest              sha256:28d4c5234db8d5a634d5e621c363d900f8f241240ee0a6a978784c978fe9c737   c73a085dc378      3 days ago

> docker history ubuntu                                                                                                                                     
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT                                         
c73a085dc378        3 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/bash"]            0 B
```

In the output, the "image ID" is actually the digest of the leaf layer, whereas the image itself has a different digest.

Docker calls this **content addressable IDs** - the rationale is explained in [the Docker 1.10 release notes](https://blog.docker.com/2016/01/docker-1-10-rc/), and there's a very thorough walkthrough in Nigel Brown's blog post [Explaining Docker Image IDs](http://windsock.io/explaining-docker-image-ids/).

Comment: With `leaf layer` did you intend the container layer (i.e. the writable layer on top of the layer stack)?

Comment: No, the leaf layer is the 'top' layer in the image (where the `FROM` image is the 'bottom' layer). The writeable layer for the container is on top of the leaf layer from the image.